# How to edit a pdf generated using iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

[image: pdf generated using iReport]

I have generated this pdf using iReport. Now while viewing this pdf using document viewer, I need to edit that gross amount field and take print out. No need to saving the edited file. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

iReports Custom Fields for columns (sum, average, etc)

Right-Click on Variables and click Create Variable

Click on the new variable

a. Notice the properties on the right

Rename the variable accordingly

Change the Value Class Name to the correct Data Type

a. You can search by clicking the 3 dots

Select the correct type of calculation

Change the Expression

a. Click the little icon

b. Select the column you are looking to do the calculation for

c. Click finish

Set Initial Value Expression to 0

Set the increment type to none

Leave Incrementer Factory Class Name blank
Set the Reset Type (usually report)

Drag a new Text Field to stage (Usually in Last Page Footer, or Column Footer)

Double Click the new Text Field
Clear the expression “Text Field”
Select the new variable

Click finish

Put the new text in a desirable position 